# GetEntityMetadata returns 0 attributes

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, crm, xrm

I need to get all the fields for a specific entity. I am currently using `Xrm.Utility.getEntityMetadata("entity_name").then(success, failure);` but on success the data returned has no attributes. Got any idea why?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! This is a community that you should try and think of as Wikipedia. Users come here with a specific question in mind, looking for a specific answer. Therefore, we require a description of the problem, your own attempt at solving the problem, the errors you are getting and what the expected output is. If those boxes are ticked, some kind volunteer may help you out. Please refer to this for more information on how to ask questions here: stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass a string array of attributes list as second parameter to get them.

```
Xrm.Utility.getEntityMetadata("account", ["accountname", "createdon"]).then(success);
```

[image]

[Read more](https://debajmecrm.com/xrm-utility-getentitymetadata-have-you-explored-it-yet-to-get-metadata-in-dynamics-365/)

Comment: Okay, what about retrieving all the fields of the entity, without having to write them manually on the argument list?